# Inserting /updating mysql record query error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query to update data if it exists or to insert new record.  The query also runs in a for loop:

```
  $pname = $c_info['name'];
  $cname = $model[$c_id]['name'];

$iqs =" IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM custom_question_details WHERE Quiz_id 
=$data[$i] and User_id=$user_id and Parent_Category='$pname' and 
Category_Name='$cname' and Score=$temp )     
UPDATE custom_question_details SET Quiz_id =$data[$i],User_id=$user_id,
Parent_Category='$pname', Category_Name='$cname',Score=$temp
ELSE
insert into custom_question_details (User_id,Quiz_id,Parent_Category,Category_Name,Score) 
values  (".$user_id.",".$data[$i].",'".$c_info['name']."','".$model[$c_id]['name']."','".$temp."')";

echo "<br>".$iqs;
```

I obtain variable values by doing certain computations in a PHP script.

These is some error with the query.  On echoing the above sql query, this data is printed, too.

```
IF EXISTS (
SELECT * 
FROM custom_question_details
WHERE Quiz_id =7
AND User_id =3
AND Parent_Category =  'Default for System'
AND Category_Name =  'sample quiz question 1'
)UPDATE custom_question_details SET Quiz_id =7,User_id=3,Parent_Category='Default for    System',Category_Name='sample quiz question 1',Score='100' 

ELSE insert into custom_question_details    (User_id,Quiz_id,Parent_Category,Category_Name,Score) values(3,7,'Default for System','sample quiz question 1','100')
```

Why is my query wrong?   I Even tried:

```
SELECT EXISTS (
SELECT * 
FROM custom_question_details
WHERE Quiz_id =7
AND User_id =3
AND Parent_Category =  'Default for System'
AND Category_Name =  'sample quiz question 1'
)UPDATE custom_question_details SET Quiz_id =7,User_id=3,
Parent_Category='Default for System',Category_Name='sample quiz question 1',Score='100' 
ELSE 
insert into custom_question_details     (User_id,Quiz_id,Parent_Category,Category_Name,Score) values(3,7,'Default for System','sample quiz question 1','100')
```

...but it still don't work. Where I am going wrong?

Comment: It does't look like you're doing any [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) at all here and probably have some severe [SQL injection bugs]. [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and provides a simple, reliable way of adding data to queries. A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) outlines the recommended best practices when interfacing with databases.

Comment: From [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/if.html): "The `IF` statement for **stored programs** implements a basic conditional construct." This is not something that can be used in general queries.

Answer (score 0):

First, the IF condition syntax is like this:

```
IF EXISTS ([condition]) THEN [your code] ELSE [some other code]
```

Secondly, I think you are missing some parentheses for the UPDATE method.
And third, I am not sure if you can use more then one column in a IF condition. I need to research that one a bit more.

Maybe you can tell us the exact error you are receiving?!

Hope it helps,
Denis Rendler

Comment: PS: I strongly advise that you look into PDO and start using prepared statements not only for code visibility but for security as well.

Comment: Here is the link to the MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html

Comment: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM custom_question_details WHERE Quiz_id =7 and User_id=3 ' at line 1 this is the error i get while executing the query

Comment: Hello. Try changing the SELECT to only use 1 column. As I understand your query you only need one column anyway.